# SQL Developer Will Not Launch (Windows 10)

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I downloaded Oracle Database 11g Express Edition, followed by downloading SQL Developer 4.1.3 with JDK 8 included to my Windows 10 machine. I even downloaded the latest version of Java separately just to cover myself. I'll double click on "start database" and absolutely nothing opens.

Any advice to get it to work?

Comment: Is the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable set up properly?

Comment: Not entirely sure, can you explain how I can check?

Comment: Before that, can you run `sqldeveloper.exe` using command prompt and show the errors you're getting from there?

Comment: I can get the command prompt up, but I have no errors popping up

Comment: Refer to [this](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/) to set up `JAVA_HOME`

Comment: Update `sqldeveloper.conf` and target the correct `JAVA_HOME` location if required.

Comment: Did you actually install the database?

Comment: Also, please note that the database is a completely separate product from SQL Developer. Your title says "SQL Developer will not launch" but then you talk about the database and "start database" which are unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you click "start database" that will NOT launch SQLDeveloper, it will start the database services. That would not normally lead to any window popping up, it runs silently in the background (as you can verify from the task manager and services windows).
Find the proper icon to launch SQLDeveloper and use that instead.

Comment: Yeah, this is pretty much what I was doing wrong the entire time. Appreciate you pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while trying to install it.
It worked after doing the steps below.

1. search sqldeveloper.exe
2. right click on this executable file
3. run as administrator
4. installation starts and the developer opens
   Hope will help.
   Regards